# How to add One to One relationship with an Embeddable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Requirement:**

To fetch the list of requests along with the requests feedback status.

**What I'm doing now :**
Fetch all the requests using JPQL query. Loop through  each request and fetch status and set into response dto.

What I want to doing.
Fetch all the request along with the status using JPQl query

**What I'm looking for :**

How can I add one to one mapping for requests & status, so that I can fetch status.

### Sample code

This is the MSREQUEST entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MSREQUEST")
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    private long requestId;

    @Column(name = "DESC")
    private string desc;

    //getter.. setter...tostring and hashcode

}
```

This is the status entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FEEDBACKSTATUS")
public class FeedbackStatus implements Serializable {

    // composite-id key
    @EmbeddedId
    private RequestFeedBackId requestFeedbackKey = new RequestFeedBackId();

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private Long status;

    //getter.. setter...tostring and hashcode

}
```

This is the embeddable entity

```
@Embeddable
public class RequestFeedBackId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="REQUESTID")
    private Long  requestId;

    @Column(name="FEEDBACKID")
    private Long feedbackId;


}
```

Service

```
@Override
public List<MsaRequestSearchDto> searchMsaRequests(MsaRequestSearchDto msaRequestSearchDto)
        throws MsaException, Exception {
    List<MsaRequestSearchDto> msaRequestSearchDtoList = msaRequestRepoCustom.findMsaRequests(msaRequestSearchDto);

    *// get feedback status loop thru and fetch status for each one. nee to avoid this
    if(msaRequestSearchDtoList != null && msaRequestSearchDtoList.size() > 0){
        // code to fetch dstatus
    }*/
    return msaRequestSearchDtoList;
}
```

JPQL query that Im using..

```
public String GET_MSA_REQUEST = "SELECT dsr FROM Request dsr  WHERE 1=1";
```

E-R
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at examples/documentation for `@Embeddable`? E.g. https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-embeddable-demo/

Comment: @JensSchauder Yes I had gone through, but that had already achieved.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Did that solve your problem? If not show us what you tried and what error/undesired behavior you get.